# How can I put kendo sparklines in all rows?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, sparklines

I put sparklines in the column usage, but it has only one row, how can I put all the rows in column usage?

I also put some of the Code relating to the usage column

[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/hRJfv/27/embedded/result/)

```
columns: [{
         {
        field: "Usage",
        title: "Usage",
        template: '<span id="sparkline"style="line-height: 60px ; padding: 0 5px 0spx ; text-align: center" ></span>'
    }, {
        command: ["edit"],
        title: "&nbsp;"
    }],
    editable: "popup",

});
```

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you use `id` in a template: `id` must be unique.

Change `id` by `class`

```
template: '<span class="sparkline"style="line-height: 60px ; padding: 0 5px 0spx ; text-align: center" ></span>'
```

and then in the initialization use:

```
$(".sparkline").kendoSparkline({...});
```

instead of:

```
$("#sparkline").kendoSparkline({});
```

See it here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/72KUP/embedded/result/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but a question of how much longer can I remove the white background in sparklines?                                 https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1mp20mw7izrycq2/WSyJAHGW2Q/white-background.PNG

Comment: Use [`chartArea.background`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/sparkline#configuration-chartArea.background)